# Thermal expansion itemduct not extracting items from chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I have a fluctuating itemduct connecting a vanilla chest to an item tesseract, I tried to attach a pneumatic servo and use a wrench, but I can't get the itemduct to extract, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try chest to chest first so you avoid bad tesseract configuration

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the servo is installed and set to remove things from the chest. Also try powering the itemduct, and making sure it is set to remove. Also make sure there is somewhere for items to go.

Comment: The itemduct won't let me add the servo

Comment: In that case, use a wrench to make the itemduct remove items (red arrow pointing out), and then supply a redstone current to it so the red arrow lights up.

Comment: When I do that it disconnects the duct from the chest

Comment: When you use the wrench it will rotate through 4 modes, none, disconnected, removal and insertion. Keep going until you get a blue arrow facing out the chest.